# Is it safe in ZeroMQ to zmq_poll() a REP socket + send() from multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, zeromq, polling, reply

I am wondering if a ZeroMQ **`REP`** socket is allowed to be `poll()`-ed on incoming data in one thread and used to send data from the other thread.

The idea I am trying to follow is the following:
A `REP` socket is not going to receive anything, as long as it did not send a reply to the incoming request. Thus if a `zmq_poll()` was called for such a socket, it'd just block (until timeout or forever).

Now, while this socket is a part of the `zmq_poll()` call for incoming data, what happens if another thread prepared a reply and uses this socket to send this reply.

Is is safe to do so or are race conditions possible than?

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ has been built on a set of a few maxims.

Zero-sharing is one of these core maxims.

While a user can at her/his own risk experiment with sharing, ZeroMQ best practices avoid doing that, except for very few and very specific cases and not on a socket-level. Sockets are knowingly not thread-safe, for the sake of the higher overall performance and lower latency.

This is the reason why a question "What happens if another thread ..." may sound legitimate, but not inside the domain of ZeroMQ Best Practices zone.

Comment: While I agree with your answer and also read about that ZeroMQ sockets are not thread safe to be used from multiple threads, I still feel like this is not the case with my use case. **`REP`** socket can eather read smth or write smth. And if application is organized this way is it safe to do polling while writing. **`REP`** guarantees to read entire multi-part message before it allows writing. Thus is it impossible to poll/write at the same time. I just want to get rid of filtering.

Comment: Good to know you agree with the answer provided.

Comment: ovanes, it's not clear what you hope to gain by this approach.  As @user3666197 says, ZeroMQ sockets are not thread safe.  If you really want to do it, I suggest you implement it in a test program, run it in a loop, and see how long it takes to fail.